# Update warnings and errors on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates

Recently a red warning triangle icon has appeared in the menu bar in my Dell XPS 13 laptop. When I open the menu it tells me that "update information is outdated".

[image: Update information is outdated]

I can choose Check For All Updates, and this launches a window named "Updating cache". I show the final contents below, prettified for readability.

I am not aware of any problems with my Internet connection, and could not have posted this message without an Internet connection.

What can I do to resolve these issues?

### ----------

**Failed to download repository information**
Check your Internet connection
v Details

```
W:GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1507497109,

W:The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release' is not signed.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

NOTE: I have upgraded to version 3.6, so this data is indeed out of date.

---

```
W:GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010,

W:The repository 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease' is not signed.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

---

```
W:GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010,

W:The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease' is not signed.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

---

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fta/gnome3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

---

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

---

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vincent-c/nevernote/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,

W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.,

W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
```

---

```
E:Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory),
```

---

```
E:Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory),
```

---

```
E:Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.opera.com_opera-stable_dists_stable_non-free_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable unsupported update  system-setting software and update backports!. .. check your repositories .                  /etc/apt/sources.list

Remove Opera:

```
sudo apt-get purge opera-stable

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install Opera:

```
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

You are using Xenial but your sources.list contains links for Precise. Jessie

Backup your current sources.list:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

Create a new list https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

save it and try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer?

Comment: @CharlesGreen not permit more than 8 link ''new user''